# How to find missing types of TArray-s of a script from Unreal docs?

Tags: unreal-4

I am trying to compile [code](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/WorkingwithModularCharacters/index.html) from Unreal's official docs.
Sadly, it just doesn't work out of the box.

I noticed that the types params of all instances of the TArray variables are missing in the header, so it won't compile...

```
Error: Unrecognized type 'type' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM.
```

I went over to the CPP file, and found that the SectionIDs variable is a type of:

```
TArray<FJsonSerializableArrayInt>
```

So I corrected it in the header to match this type for SectionIDs.

I am still getting the same error message.

How do you find out these template params for the TArray instances?

It's weird, that they missing, the code meant to be compiled and run in the editor straight away...

Might be the Unreal guys trolling noobs...

Code in header:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.
#pragma once
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "UObject/NoExportTypes.h"
#include "MeshMergeFunctionLibrary.generated.h"
/**
* Blueprint equivalent of FSkeleMeshMergeSectionMapping
* Info to map all the sections from a single source skeletal mesh to
* a final section entry in the merged skeletal mesh.
*/
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct PROJECTNAME_API FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** Indices to final section entries of the merged skeletal mesh */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray<type> SectionIDs;
};
/**
* Used to wrap a set of UV Transforms for one mesh.
*/
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct PROJECTNAME_API FSkelMeshMergeUVTransform
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** A list of how UVs should be transformed on a given mesh, where index represents a specific UV channel. */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray UVTransforms;
};
/**
* Blueprint equivalent of FSkelMeshMergeUVTransforms
* Info to map all the sections about how to transform their UVs
*/
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct PROJECTNAME_API FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** For each UV channel on each mesh, how the UVS should be transformed. */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray UVTransformsPerMesh;
};
/**
* Struct containing all parameters used to perform a Skeletal Mesh merge.
*/
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct PROJECTNAME_API FSkeletalMeshMergeParams
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        FSkeletalMeshMergeParams()
    {
        MeshSectionMappings = TArray();
        UVTransformsPerMesh = TArray();
        StripTopLODS = 0;
        bNeedsCpuAccess = false;
        bSkeletonBefore = false;
        Skeleton = nullptr;
    }
    // An optional array to map sections from the source meshes to merged section entries
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray MeshSectionMappings;
    // An optional array to transform the UVs in each mesh
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray UVTransformsPerMesh;
    // The list of skeletal meshes to merge.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray MeshesToMerge;
    // The number of high LODs to remove from input meshes
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int32 StripTopLODS;
    // Whether or not the resulting mesh needs to be accessed by the CPU for any reason (e.g. for spawning particle effects).
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        uint32 bNeedsCpuAccess : 1;
    // Update skeleton before merge. Otherwise, update after.
    // Skeleton must also be provided.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        uint32 bSkeletonBefore : 1;
    // Skeleton that will be used for the merged mesh.
    // Leave empty if the generated skeleton is OK.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
        class USkeleton* Skeleton;
};
/**
*
*/
UCLASS()
class PROJECTNAME_API UMeshMergeFunctionLibrary : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    /**
    * Merges the given meshes into a single mesh.
    * @return The merged mesh (will be invalid if the merge failed).
    */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Mesh Merge", meta = (UnsafeDuringActorConstruction = "true"))
        static class USkeletalMesh* MergeMeshes(const FSkeletalMeshMergeParams& Params);
};
~~~
```

And in cpp:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.
#include "MeshMergeFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "SkeletalMeshMerge.h"
#include "Engine/SkeletalMeshSocket.h"
#include "Engine/SkeletalMesh.h"
#include "Animation/Skeleton.h"
static void ToMergeParams(const TArray<FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP>& InSectionMappings, TArray<FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping>& OutSectionMappings)
{
    if (InSectionMappings.Num() > 0)
    {
        OutSectionMappings.AddUninitialized(InSectionMappings.Num());
        for (int32 i = 0; i < InSectionMappings.Num(); ++i)
        {
            OutSectionMappings[i].SectionIDs = InSectionMappings[i].SectionIDs;
        }
    }
};
static void ToMergeParams(const TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping>& InUVTransformsPerMesh, TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransforms>& OutUVTransformsPerMesh)
{
    if (InUVTransformsPerMesh.Num() > 0)
    {
        OutUVTransformsPerMesh.Empty();
        OutUVTransformsPerMesh.AddUninitialized(InUVTransformsPerMesh.Num());
        for (int32 i = 0; i < InUVTransformsPerMesh.Num(); ++i)
        {
            TArray<TArray<FTransform>>& OutUVTransforms = OutUVTransformsPerMesh[i].UVTransformsPerMesh;
            const TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransform>& InUVTransforms = InUVTransformsPerMesh[i].UVTransformsPerMesh;
            if (InUVTransforms.Num() > 0)
            {
                OutUVTransforms.Empty();
                OutUVTransforms.AddUninitialized(InUVTransforms.Num());
                for (int32 j = 0; j < InUVTransforms.Num(); j++)
                {
                    OutUVTransforms[i] = InUVTransforms[i].UVTransforms;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
USkeletalMesh* UMeshMergeFunctionLibrary::MergeMeshes(const FSkeletalMeshMergeParams& Params)
{
    TArray<USkeletalMesh*> MeshesToMergeCopy = Params.MeshesToMerge;
    MeshesToMergeCopy.RemoveAll([](USkeletalMesh* InMesh)
    {
        return InMesh == nullptr;
    });
    if (MeshesToMergeCopy.Num() <= 1)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Must provide multiple valid Skeletal Meshes in order to perform a merge."));
        return nullptr;
    }
    EMeshBufferAccess BufferAccess = Params.bNeedsCpuAccess ?
        EMeshBufferAccess::ForceCPUAndGPU :
        EMeshBufferAccess::Default;
    TArray<FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping> SectionMappings;
    TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransforms> UvTransforms;
    ToMergeParams(Params.MeshSectionMappings, SectionMappings);
    ToMergeParams(Params.UVTransformsPerMesh, UvTransforms);
    bool bRunDuplicateCheck = false;
    USkeletalMesh* BaseMesh = NewObject<USkeletalMesh>();
    if (Params.Skeleton && Params.bSkeletonBefore)
    {
        BaseMesh->Skeleton = Params.Skeleton;
        bRunDuplicateCheck = true;
        for (USkeletalMeshSocket* Socket : BaseMesh->GetMeshOnlySocketList())
        {
            if (Socket)
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelMeshSocket: %s"), *(Socket->SocketName.ToString()));
            }
        }
        for (USkeletalMeshSocket* Socket : BaseMesh->Skeleton->Sockets)
        {
            if (Socket)
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelSocket: %s"), *(Socket->SocketName.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    FSkeletalMeshMerge Merger(BaseMesh, MeshesToMergeCopy, SectionMappings, Params.StripTopLODS, BufferAccess, UvTransforms.GetData());
    if (!Merger.DoMerge())
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Merge failed!"));
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (Params.Skeleton && !Params.bSkeletonBefore)
    {
        BaseMesh->Skeleton = Params.Skeleton;
    }
    if (bRunDuplicateCheck)
    {
        TArray<FName> SkelMeshSockets;
        TArray<FName> SkelSockets;
        for (USkeletalMeshSocket* Socket : BaseMesh->GetMeshOnlySocketList())
        {
            if (Socket)
            {
                SkelMeshSockets.Add(Socket->GetFName());
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelMeshSocket: %s"), *(Socket->SocketName.ToString()));
            }
        }
        for (USkeletalMeshSocket* Socket : BaseMesh->Skeleton->Sockets)
        {
            if (Socket)
            {
                SkelSockets.Add(Socket->GetFName());
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelSocket: %s"), *(Socket->SocketName.ToString()));
            }
        }
        TSet<FName> UniqueSkelMeshSockets;
        TSet<FName> UniqueSkelSockets;
        UniqueSkelMeshSockets.Append(SkelMeshSockets);
        UniqueSkelSockets.Append(SkelSockets);
        int32 Total = SkelSockets.Num() + SkelMeshSockets.Num();
        int32 UniqueTotal = UniqueSkelMeshSockets.Num() + UniqueSkelSockets.Num();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelMeshSocketCount: %d | SkelSocketCount: %d | Combined: %d"), SkelMeshSockets.Num(), SkelSockets.Num(), Total);
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SkelMeshSocketCount: %d | SkelSocketCount: %d | Combined: %d"), UniqueSkelMeshSockets.Num(), UniqueSkelSockets.Num(), UniqueTotal);
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Found Duplicates: %s"), *((Total != UniqueTotal) ? FString("True") : FString("False")));
    }
    return BaseMesh;
}
```